# Regex with 3 digits or 4 alphanumeric characters c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to create a regex to validate if a string has a maximum of 3 digits or a maximum of 4 alphanumeric characters, for example those are valid:

- 123, 000, abc1, a1bc, 1abc, 123a

This ones shouldn't be valid:

- 1234, 123mx, abcd0

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "abcd";
        var newRegx = @"(^[0-9]{1,3}$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}$)";    
        Regex rgx = new Regex(newRegx);
        
        Console.WriteLine ("regex: "+ newRegx);
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="0000")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="01mk")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="k")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="987io")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="ff123")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="12")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="102n")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
        Console.WriteLine ("\n'"+(text="1230")+"' matches? "+ rgx.IsMatch(text) );
    }
}
```

It produces this:

```
regex: (^[0-9]{1,3}$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}$)
'0000' matches? True
'01mk' matches? True
'k' matches? True
'987io' matches? False
'ff123' matches? False
'12' matches? True
'102n' matches? True
'1234' matches? True
```

You can run it here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vWyzD0

The problem is with last example (1234), it shouldn't be valid but my regex is assuming that it is an alphanumeric string and not a number, how can fix my regex?

Comment: So it boils down to "1234", that should not be valid under "4 alphanumeric characters" rules? https://regex101.com/r/gCoiwq/1

Comment: for the second one you can say that it should at least contain one character, you might have to validate two time

Comment: Why should `'0000'` be valid?

Comment: the correct should be '000' because it has only 3 digits, but my regex was allowing it 'cause needed something more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add negative lookahead `(?!\d{4})` before the second part of or statement
`(^[0-9]{1,3}$)|(^(?!\d{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}$)` so that 4 digits aren't accepted

https://dotnetfiddle.net/CbGSlG

Comment: @StevenArturoBrenesGonzález The first part `^[0-9]{1,3}$)` looks to be redundant, enough to use e.g. [`^(?!\d{4})[a-zA-Z\d]{1,4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/NRL4On/1).